# End of statement error while naming a workbook by adding some strings

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub openwb()

Dim sb As String

Dim wb, dwb As Workbook

Dim ws As Worksheet

Set dwb = ActiveWorkbook

Set ws = dwb.Sheets("Home")

sb = ws.Range("F4").Value

Set wb = sb&"_Powertrain Metrics_" & (Format(Date, "YYYYMMDD") & ".xlsm")

Debug.Print wb

End Sub
```

Here on 8th line, the portion `"_Powertrain Metrics_"` is highlighted and says "Compile error:Expected end of statement". Can u tell me what is the problem here?Is it anything about strings i used?

Comment: + 1 BTW, I am happy that you finally have started declaring and using objects :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A**. Change

`Dim wb, dwb As Workbook`

to

`Dim wb As Workbook, dwb As Workbook`

In VBA you have to explicitly declare the variables else they will be considered as variants.

**B**. Change

`Set wb = sb&"_Powertrain Metrics_" & (Format(Date, "YYYYMMDD") & ".xlsm")`

to

`Set wb = Workbooks.Open(sb & "_Powertrain Metrics_" & Format(Date, "YYYYMMDD") & ".xlsm")`

You were missing a `SPACE` before and after the `&`

Comment: Now the line says "Object required". And when i tried to put it like

Set wb = Workbooks(sb & "_Powertrain Metrics_" & (Format(Date, "YYYYMMDD") & ".xlsm"))

Then it says,"subscript out of range".
But about the change B, it used to automatically put a space when we use '&' operator.The other two & operators worked in that way.

Comment: My apologies... Updated the post above